# Why do float literals and variables give different results in Go?

Tags: go

In the simple calculations below, `c` and `d` end up with different values (they're off by a single bit). Why is that?

```
a := 4000.0
b := 1e-9
c := a / b
d := 4000.0 / 1e-9
```

Comment: I guess it has to do with implicit typing, but it's weird.

Comment: Just in case anyone wants to play with it: http://play.golang.org/p/gkoUVAIrIy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` is assigned the next-best value for `4000.0` represented as a `float64`, which is `0x40AF400000000000` and corresponds to exactly `4000.0`.

`b` is the next-best value for `1e-9`, represented as a `float64`, which is `0x3E112E0BE826D695` and corresponds to `1.00000000000000006228159145778E-9`. You lost precision here.

So before computing `c` you already have a slight imprecision. Then when `c` is actually calculated you lose some more precision to rounding.

In the case of `d`, there is only one "next-besting" going on; when representing the compile-time calculated full-precision value of `4000.0 / 1e-9` as a `float64`.

An aside about variables: In C (and presumably C++), the default is to assume a variable is non-volatile i.e. not shared and hence optimizations often follow constant-expressions deeply, replacing everything with computed values. Go makes no assumptions about the scope of variables and hence no guarantees about replacing constant expressions. This may change in the future but today, not much is done in that department so it's quite possible that `c` is actually calculated at runtime, not at compile-time as someone used to C might think.

---

Edit: I have taken the program provided by @topskip:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := 4000.0
    b := 1e-9
    c := a / b
    d := 4000.0 / 1e-9
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(b)
    fmt.Println(c)
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

And this is part of the assembly generated by `go tool 6g -S`:

```
0x0021 00033 (meh.go:6) MOVSD   $f64.40af400000000000+0(SB),X2
0x002a 00042 (meh.go:7) MOVSD   $f64.3e112e0be826d695+0(SB),X3
0x0033 00051 (meh.go:8) MOVAPD  X2,X0
0x0037 00055 (meh.go:8) MOVSD   X3,"".b+64(SP)
0x003d 00061 (meh.go:8) DIVSD   X3,X0
```

As you can see; `c` is calculated at runtime based on the two constants I describe.

Comment: FWIW, gccgo evaluates the expression at compile time.

Comment: Nothing in the language spec or memory model prevents a compiler from computing `c` at compile time.  You are observing a limitation of the gc compiler, not a language feature.

Comment: @Steve nobody said it was a language feature. But if you want to know; [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) does not define `a / b` as a constant expression, because `a` and `b` are **variables**. As such, a compliant implementation _should_ evaluate `c`'s value at runtime, unless it can prove correctness, of course.

Comment: The specification specifies an order for evaluating variable expressions, but makes not statement that the expressions must be evaluated at runtime. As noted by another commenter, one of the Go compilers does evaluate the expression at compile time.